# Rails Tutorial signed_in? Function Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial and in Chapter 8 it has you creating the user sessions to sign in. For some reason the `signed_in?` function doesn't seem to be working - I always get the "Sign in" link, instead of the "Sign out" link when the user is actually signed in.

Any idea where I'm going wrong in my code?

Application.html.erb (where I do `<% if signed_in? %>`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample App</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <% if signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %>
        <% end %>
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attributes(remember_token: remember_token)
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Application Controller (which has the session helper added in it):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

The Session Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I think my biggest stumbling block has been trying to figure out how to actually debug and test that 1. the user is actually being signed in and 2. that the signed_in? function is firing but I can't seem to figure out how to debug test this. Any tips/pointers on how to do that would also be much appreciated! I was trying to log stuff to the Chrome console, but it seems like that's javascript only and rails can't log there.

**EDIT**: Adding Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token

  validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that tutorial but the problem seems to be here:

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attributes(remember_token: remember_token) # 1
  self.current_user = user
end

def current_user
  remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token]) # 2
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

1. you save one value in the user (`remember_token`)
2. But you use another value to look users up (`digest(remember_token)`).

That's why you don't find a current user, I think.

### Tips for debugging

1. Use `pry`
2. Use `pry-debugger`
3. Put a lot of debug print statements in the code and watch the logs (to make sure that they output what you expect). I mean server logs, of course (`log/development.log`)
4. If they don't output what you expect, then put a `binding.pry` in there and drop into interactive debugger. It's basically a console in the middle of execution of your code (you can evaluate and change stuff, and step through the code, line by line)